# PL/SQL procedure has mutliple 'AND' conditions and OR comditions . How to make sure all conditions it executes?

Tags: plsql

```
*where  (citiStatus NOT IN ('Paid Off' ,'PAID-O'))
    and (
            revolver = 0
                and (
                    (commitmentDate = '')
                    or (
                        (commitmentDate != '')
                        and (@currentDate < DATEADD(day, @noofDays, commitmentDate))
                        )
                    )   
        )   // until here should verify with where condition . even if it is failed or not should execute next statement .
    and (citiStatus NOT IN ('CANCELLED','Cancelled/Dead') or @currentMonth = MONTH(statusModifiedDate))-- this is will if above AND condition fails even if its true(but this should execute even to filter data).*
```

Comment: Please expand and clarify you issue before someone downvotes your question.

Comment: What is "PLSQL" tag in your question? It is related to Oracle, but - code you wrote isn't Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have in mind two simple rules, the Associativity of Logical Operators is always from left to right, and the correct use of Parentheses having in consideration the logic of your problem for example:

```
select case when 1=1 and 1=2 or 3=3 then 1 else 0 end as result from dual;--result 1
```

First we evaluate 3=3 TRUE -> 1=2 FALSE -> evaluate OR OPERATOR (TRUE OR FALSE)-> TRUE
Second 1=1 TRUE -> evaluate AND OPERATOR -> TRUE AND TRUE -> TRUE
IF TRUE THEN 1

My advice is always to use Parentheses, in this way you will evaluate the whole expression and no token by token for example

```
select case when ((1=1 and 2=2) or 3=3) and 5=6 then 1 else 0 end as result from dual; --0

select case when (1=1 and 2=2) or (3=3 and 5=6) then 1 else 0 end as result from dual;  --1
```

Comment: if it is where condition how should i evaluate ?

Comment: You should play with the logic of your problem. `select 1  as result from dual 
where (case when (1=1 and 2=2) or (3=3 and 5=6) then 1 else 0 end) = 1; --1`